# Communicating between react components in play scala application

Tags: scala, reactjs, playframework, redux

My play / scala application uses Twirl engine based UI and I use React for various pieces embedded here and there (objective is to use Scala's type-safety as much as possible). Trying to minimize JS/jQuery foot print.

I want to know if a React component can communicate with another one (without a common parent). Say if I remove an entry in one table, corresponding entry in the second table should be removed as well. If there is an enclosing React class I can use React state to control but dont have such a container class.

Can Redux/MobX stores be used in this situation ?

Comment: The Redux approach would definitely work. If your components live in a completely separate root components your only option seems to be some kind of global event system.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMihaylov will try Redux